# PHP Code Formatting

Tags: php

Which formatting is correct? I don't know exactly how to indent PHP code yet. I feel like Set 2 is correct but I don't know yet.

**Set 1**

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'ijdbuser', 'ijdbpw');

if (!$connection)
{
    $error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8'))
{
    $output = 'Unable to set database connection encoding.';
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($connection 'ijdb'))
{
    $error = 'Unable to locate the joke database.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT joketext FROM joke");

        if (!$result)
        {
            $error = 'Error fetching jokes: ' . mysqli_error($connection
            );
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                {  
                    $jokes[] = $row['joketext'];  
                }  
                include 'jokes.html.php';  

?>
```

**Set 2**

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'ijdbuser', 'ijdbpw');

if (!$connection)
{
    $error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8'))
{
    $output = 'Unable to set database connection encoding.';
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($connection 'ijdb'))
{
    $error = 'Unable to locate the joke database.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT joketext FROM joke");

if (!$result)
{
    $error = 'Error fetching jokes: ' . mysqli_error($connection
    );
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
    $jokes[] = $row['joketext'];  
}  
include 'jokes.html.php';  

?>
```

Comment: #2 is correct. Statements that are at the same nesting level should be indented the same.

Comment: Why aren't you using an editor that indents your code automatically for you?

Comment: For the standard coding styles take a look at the [PHP-Fig website](http://www.php-fig.org/) especially PSR 1 and PSR 2

Comment: I'm using Sublime. I'm new to Sublime 3 so maybe I don't have the plugin to do indenting. If you know of a plugin let me know. Thx. So for my if statements the left curly bracket should be if (!$result) { on the same line as opposed to if (!$result) <newline> {. Is that right, according to PSR 2?

Comment: what the IDE did you used ？ The PatentStorm will prefect format you code,it's support flexible format configurations.

Comment: I just started using Sublime3 over Notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *"right"* or *"wrong"* formatting, not really. Just be consistent, and choose the style you like best. However, there is such a thing as [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/). The coding style they propose is the most commonly adopted one, and the one you'll see used in almost all major open-source projects.

Personally, I try to subscribe to their coding standard as much as possible, though I tend to prefer allman-style brackets, too (`if ()\n{\n`). I think I sent them a PR a few years back to allow for that indentation style, too, but it got rejected (mainly to avoid having merge conflicts surrounding conflicting whitespace, so I understand where they're coming from).

Comment: While there are lots of detailed style recommendations that are matter of opinion, I don't think there's any disagreement about basic indenting. His first version is really wrong.

Comment: @barmar: It's wrong in the sense that the indentation looks like it's a copy-paste job into vim without a `:set paste`, but the code itself works, and is syntactically valid (PHP not having significant whitespace). But I agree, and I'll edit my answer to reflect on the nonsensicalness  of the indentation in the first snippet

Comment: The only difference I can see between the two versions is the indentation. And his question specifically asks about style.

Answer (score 1):

[PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) - These are not law-like rules but if you follow these you can not be wrong.

Comment: Don't post link-only answers. Copy the relevant text from the remote site into your answer, and use the link for support. I couldn't even find the answer to his question in there myself.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this. PHP beautifier can also help alot.

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'ijdbuser', 'ijdbpw');

if (!$connection)
    {
    $error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
    include 'error.html.php';

    exit();
    }

if (!mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8'))
    {
    $output = 'Unable to set database connection encoding.';
    include 'output.html.php';

    exit();
    }

if (!mysqli_select_db($connection'ijdb'))
    {
    $error = 'Unable to locate the joke database.';
    include 'error.html.php';

    exit();
    }

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT joketext FROM joke");

if (!$result)
    {
    $error = 'Error fetching jokes: ' . mysqli_error($connection);
    include 'error.html.php';

    exit();
    }

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $jokes[] = $row['joketext'];
    }

include 'jokes.html.php';

?>
```

Comment: I don't like this formatting at all. Also, if it is your personal preference please state it, otherwise refer the style guide you're using.

Comment: I stated the source to be PHP beatifier. I have lots of preference especially when building classes.

Answer (score 1):

## Set 2

seems more readable. Yes, clean, readability, clear, easy to maintain are some factors to more than just standards. Have a look at [Proposed Standards Recommendation (PSR)](http://www.php-fig.org/) but also look at different php **open source frameworks** and their style guides or coding convention or contributions styleguide on github.

For example:

- [Zend Framework Styleguide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html)
- [Laravel 5](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/contributions#coding-style) uses a combination of PSR-4 and PSR-1

I go with what the team and community/organisation of the project is most comfortable with.. fluid.

Also will help by: ( [Clean Code by Robert C.Martin](https://cleansourcecode.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/clean-code.pdf) )

Hope this helps.